# Single player console Blackjack game

Tags: c#, .net, playing-cards

This is just a single player versus a dealer. I'm not worried about execution time. It does not perform bets - it only track wins and losses- and has no splitting. Other than that I tried to get it all in.

I take it most people know Backjack. Number are the number, face cards are 10, and ace is 1 or 11. Player has no rules about hitting  (take a card).  Dealer has to hit to 17. Closest to 21 without going over wins.  Dealer wins a tie.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BlackJack blackJack = new BlackJack();
        //blackJack.PlayHand();
        blackJack.PlayGame();
    }
    public class Card
    {
        private enum CardRank { Two = 0, Three = 1, Four = 2, Five = 3, Six = 4, Seven = 5, Eight = 6, Nine = 7, Ten = 8, Jack = 9, Queen = 10, King = 11, Ace = 12 }
        private enum CardSuit { Spade = 0, Club = 1, Heart = 2, Diamond = 3 }
        int i;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ((CardRank)(i % 13)).ToString() + " " + ((CardSuit)(i / 13)).ToString();
        }
        public int Value
        {
            get
            {
                int value;
                if (i % 13 == 12)
                {
                    value = 11;
                }
                else
                {
                    value = i % 13 + 2;
                    if (value > 10)
                    {
                        value = 10;
                    }
                }
                return value;
            }
        }
        public Card(int I)
        {
            i = I;
        }
    }
    public abstract class Seat
    {
        public int AceCount { get; private set; } = 0;
        public List<Card> Cards { get; private set; } = new List<Card>(); 
        public bool Busted
        { get { return Total > 21; } }
        public bool HasBlackJack
        { get{ return (Total == 21 && Cards.Count == 2); } }
        public int Total
        {
            get
            {
                int total = 0;
                AceCount = 0;
                foreach (Card c in Cards)
                {
                    total += c.Value;
                }
                if (total > 21 && AceCount > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < AceCount; i++)
                    {
                        total -= 10;
                        if (total <= 21)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return total;
            }
        }
        public abstract bool CanHit { get; }
        public void HitMe(Card C)
        {
            Cards.Add(C);
        }
        public virtual string DisplayCards
        {
            get
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (Card c in Cards)
                {
                    if(sb.Length > 0)
                    {
                        sb.Append(", ");
                    }
                    sb.Append(c.ToString());
                } 
                string cards = sb.ToString();
                return $"{cards} {Total}";
            }
        }
    }
    public class Dealer : Seat
    {
        public override bool CanHit
        {
            get
            {
                if (AceCount > 0)
                {
                    return Total <= 18;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Total <= 17;
                }
            }
        }
        public override string DisplayCards
        {
            get
            {
                if(Cards.Count == 2)
                {
                    return $"{Cards[0].ToString()} {Cards[0].Value}";
                }
                else
                {
                    return base.DisplayCards;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Player : Seat
    {
        public override bool CanHit
        {
            get
            {
                return Total < 21;
            }
        }

        public int Wins { get; set; } = 0;
        public int Loss { get; set; } = 0;
        public string WinLoss
        {
            get { return $"Win {Wins} Loss {Loss}"; }
        }
    }
    public class BlackJack
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        private List<Card> Deck;
        private int deckPos = -1;
        Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
        Player player = new Player();
        private void Shuffle()
        {
            deckPos = -1;
            int swap;
            Card temp;
            for (int i = Deck.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                swap = rand.Next(i + 1);  //.net rand is not inclusive
                if (swap != i)
                {
                    temp = Deck[i];
                    Deck[i] = Deck[swap];
                    Deck[swap] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        public BlackJack()
        {
            Deck = new List<Card>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {
                Card card = new Card(i);
                Console.WriteLine(card.ToString());
                Deck.Add(card);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Shuffle();
        }
        private Card Pop()
        {
            deckPos++;
            return (Deck[deckPos]);
        }
        private Card Peek()
        {
            return (Deck[deckPos]);
        }
        public void PlayGame()
        {           
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("C to continue Q to quit");
                string p = Console.ReadLine();
                if (p == "C" || p == "c")
                {
                    PlayHand();
                }
                else if (p == "Q" || p == "q")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bye");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void PlayHand()
        {
            if (deckPos > 30)
            {
                Shuffle();
            }

            dealer.Cards.Clear();
            player.Cards.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Card card = Pop();
            dealer.HitMe(card);
            dealer.HitMe(Pop());
            Console.WriteLine("Dealer");
            Console.WriteLine(dealer.DisplayCards);
            if (dealer.HasBlackJack)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player H to hit  S to Stay");
                player.Loss++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player H to hit  S to Stay");
                player.HitMe(Pop());
                player.HitMe(Pop());
                Console.WriteLine(player.DisplayCards);
                string p;
                while (true)
                {
                    p = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (p == "H" || p == "h")
                    {
                        if (player.CanHit)
                        {
                            player.HitMe(Pop());
                            Console.WriteLine(player.DisplayCards);
                            if (player.Busted)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (player.HasBlackJack)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (p == "S" || p == "s")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (player.Busted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player busted out dealer wins");
                    player.Loss++;
                }
                else if (player.HasBlackJack)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Blackjack player wins");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Dealer");
                    while (dealer.CanHit)
                    {
                        dealer.HitMe(Pop());
                        Console.WriteLine(dealer.DisplayCards);
                        if (dealer.Busted)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (dealer.Busted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Dealer busted out player wins");
                        player.Wins++;
                    }
                    else if (dealer.Total >= player.Total)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Dealer wins");
                        player.Loss++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Player wins");
                        player.Wins++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(player.WinLoss);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your code have a bad formatting. It is hard to read it without, for example, empty lines between methods and properties.

Also it is almost always better to follow the rule: one file - one class.

One of big disadvantages of your code is you totally ignore the great feature of C# - **LINQ**.

Some examples of how you can make your code better. This property

> ```
> public int Total
> {
>     get
>     {
>         int total = 0;
>         AceCount = 0;
>         foreach (Card c in Cards)
>         {
>             total += c.Value;
>         }
>         if (total > 21 && AceCount > 0)
>         {
>             for (int i = 0; i < AceCount; i++)
>             {
>                 total -= 10;
>                 if (total <= 21)
>                 {
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         return total;
>     }
> }
> ```

can be rewritten as (by the way I don't understand when `for` will be executed if you set `AceCount = 0` above it)

```
 public int Total
 {
     get
     {
         AceCount = 0;
         int total = Cards.Sum(c => c.Value);
         for (int i = 0; i < AceCount && total > 21; i++)
         {
             total -= 10;
         }
         return total;
     }
 }
```

This property

> ```
> public virtual string DisplayCards
> {
>     get
>     {
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>         foreach (Card c in Cards)
>         {
>             if(sb.Length > 0)
>             {
>                 sb.Append(", ");
>             }
>             sb.Append(c.ToString());
>         } 
>         string cards = sb.ToString();
>         return $"{cards} {Total}";
>     }
> }
> ```

can be rewritten as

```
public virtual string DisplayCards
{
    get
    {
        var cards = string.Join(", ", Cards);
        return $"{cards} {Total}";
    }
}
```

In my opinion these two examples ideally show your coding style and how it can be improved.

Also these lines

> ```
> Console.WriteLine(card.ToString());
> Console.WriteLine("");
> ```

look very strange. They should be replaced with

```
Console.WriteLine(card);
Console.WriteLine();
```

And please get rid of magic number constants. Define named `const`'s like

```
private const int DeckSize = 52;
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to encapsulate _magic-conditions_ like this one `i < AceCount && total > 21`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: I had it var cards = string.Join(Cards , ", "); so it was not working and I gave up.  In the Cards.Sum is where I am supposed to be counting aces so I cannot use LINQ.  Good feedback.

Comment: `string.Join(", ", Cards)` is an exact eqivalent of `foreach` with `StringBuilder`. If it was not working you did something wrong.