# Blackjack game interview task

Tags: java, interview-questions, playing-cards

As part of a recent interview, I was assigned to write a small BlackJack program. After submitting the solution, I received an answer that "the solution was functionally OK, but was way below their standards of quality code, especially coming from a person with significant experience" (I have 15 years experience).

I have posted my code in order to receive an honest critical review on the quality of the code. It is true that I wrote it while on vacation, but does it really suck so much? If so, how could I have written it differently?

```
public class Deck {


    public enum CARD {
            S2(2),S3(3),S4(4),S5(5),S6(6),S7(7),S8(8),S9(9),S10(10),SJ(10),SQ(10),SK(10),SA(11),
            D2(2),D3(3),D4(4),D5(5),D6(6),D7(7),D8(8),D9(9),D10(10),DJ(10),DQ(10),DK(10),DA(11),
            C2(2),C3(3),C4(4),C5(5),C6(6),C7(7),C8(8),C9(9),C10(10),CJ(10),CQ(10),CK(10),CA(11),
            H2(2),H3(3),H4(4),H5(5),H6(6),H7(7),H8(8),H9(9),H10(10),HJ(10),HQ(10),HK(10),HA(11);

            private int points;

            private CARD(int points) {
                this.points = points;
            }

            public int getPoints() {
                return points;
            }

    }



    private Stack<CARD> deck = new Stack<Deck.CARD>();



    private Deck(Stack<CARD> deck) {
        this.deck = deck;
    }

    private Deck(){
        shuffleDeck();
    }

    private void shuffleDeck() {
        // we need it mutable and the list provided by Arrays is Immutable
        List<CARD> allCards = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(CARD.values()));
        int max = 52;
        Random rand = new Random();
        while (allCards.size()>0) {
            CARD removedCard = allCards.remove(rand.nextInt(max)) ;
            this.deck.add(removedCard);
            --max;
        }
    }


    public CARD draw() {
        return deck.pop();
    }



    public static class Builder {

        Stack<CARD> deck=null;

        public static Builder createNew(){
            return new Deck.Builder();
        }

        public  Builder fromFile(File file) throws IOException {
            Scanner scanner=null;

            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(file);
                deck = new Stack<>();
                for (String card : scanner.nextLine().split(", ")) {
                    deck.add(Enum.valueOf(CARD.class, card));
                }


            } finally {
                if (scanner!=null) {
                    scanner.close();
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        public Builder fromStack(Stack stack) {
            this.deck = stack;
            return this;
        }

        public  Builder validate() {
            if (deck==null) {
                return this;
            }
            if (deck.size()>52) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Critical error, deck is not initialized correctly.You need 52 unique cards.");

            }
            HashSet<CARD> allUniqueCards = new HashSet<>(deck==null?new HashSet<>():deck);
            // verify uniqueness of cards in case of 52 card condition is met but some are duplicates
            if (deck==null || allUniqueCards.size()==52) {
                return this;
            }
            // this is error that is not recoverable therefore we define it as RuntimeException
            throw new RuntimeException("Critical error, deck is not initialized correctly.You need 52 unique cards.");

        }

        public  Deck build() {

            return deck==null? new Deck():new Deck(deck);
        }


    } 

    public String toString() {
        String toString = deck.stream().map(t->{return t.toString()+", ";}).reduce("", (t,q)->{return t+q;});
        if (!toString.isEmpty()) {
            toString = toString.substring(0,toString.length()-2);
        }

        return toString; 
    }

}
```

Hand class

```
public class Hand {

    // in general it is one idea more correct to be Set, 
    //but I am on holiday right now and I need to write the tests fast.
    private List<CARD> hand = new ArrayList<>();


    public boolean hasBlackJack() {

        return score()==21;
    }

    public boolean has22(){
        return score()==22;
    }

    public boolean lessThan17(){
        return score()<17;
    }

    public boolean greaterThan(Hand hand) {
        return this.score()>hand.score();
    }

    public boolean greaterThan21(){
        return score()>21;
    }

    public void addCard(CARD card) {
        hand.add(card);
    }

    private int score(){
        return hand.stream().mapToInt(t->{return t.getPoints();}).sum();

    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return hand.size()==0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        // the sequential stream is not nessesary realy, but it makes it one idea easier to test later.
        String toString = hand.stream().sequential().map(t->{return t.name();}).reduce("", (t,q)->{return t.isEmpty()?q: t+", " + q;});
        return toString;
    }


}
```

Player class

```
public class Player {

    private String playerName =null;

    private Hand hand = new Hand();



    public Player(String playerName) {
        this.playerName=playerName;

    }

    public boolean hasBlackJack(){
        return hand.hasBlackJack();
    }

    public boolean has22() {
        return hand.has22();
    }

    public boolean lessThan17(){
        return hand.lessThan17();
    }

    public boolean greaterThan21() {
        return hand.greaterThan21();
    }

    public boolean hasEmptyHand() {
        return hand.empty();
    }

    public boolean handGreaterThan(Player player) {
        return this.hand.greaterThan(player.hand);
    }

    public void draw(Deck deck) {
        hand.addCard(deck.draw());
    }


    public String getPlayerName(){
        return playerName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return playerName + ":" + " " + hand.toString(); 
    }

}

    //Assumption in case of a tie SAM wins.
public class Play21 {

    Player dealer = null;
    Player sam = null;
    Deck deck =  null;


    public Play21(Player sam,Player dealer,Deck deck) {
        this.sam=sam;
        this.dealer=dealer;
        this.deck = deck;
    }

    public static void printWinner(Player winner,Player looser) {
        System.out.println(winner.getPlayerName());
        System.out.println(winner.getPlayerName().equals("sam")?winner:looser);
        System.out.println(winner.getPlayerName().equals("sam")?looser:winner);
    }




    private Player round1() {

        sam.draw(deck);
        dealer.draw(deck);
        sam.draw(deck);
        dealer.draw(deck);

        if (dealer.hasBlackJack()&&sam.hasBlackJack()) {
            return sam;
        }
        else if (sam.hasBlackJack()) {
            return sam;
        }
        else if(dealer.hasBlackJack()) {
            return dealer;
        }

        if (dealer.has22()&&sam.has22()) {
            return dealer;
        }
        else if (sam.has22()) {
            return dealer;
        }
        else if (dealer.has22()) {
            return sam;
        }

        return null;
    }



    private Player round2() {
        if (sam.hasEmptyHand()||dealer.hasEmptyHand()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You need to invoke round1 first");
        }

        while(sam.lessThan17()) {
            sam.draw(deck);
        }

        if (sam.greaterThan21()) {
            return dealer;
        }


        while (sam.handGreaterThan(dealer)) {
            dealer.draw(deck);
        }

        if (dealer.greaterThan21()) {

            return sam;
        }
        if (dealer.handGreaterThan(sam)) {
            return dealer;
        }
        else {
            return sam;
        }
    }

    public Player play(Deck deck){


        Player winner = round1();
        if (winner!=null) {
            return winner;
        }
        return round2();


    }

    public static Deck createDeck(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Deck deck =null;

        if (args.length==0) {
            deck=Deck.Builder.createNew()
                             .validate()
                             .build();
        }
        else if (args.length==1) {
            File file =  new File(args[0]);
            if (file.isFile()) {
                deck=Deck.Builder.createNew()
                                 .fromFile(file)
                                 .validate()
                                 .build();
            }
            else {
                // Unrecoverable exception therefore declared as RuntimeException
                throw new RuntimeException("Path is not a file, or file does not exist,or file is unreadable(check permissions).");
            }

        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal number of arguments. ");
        }

        return deck;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Deck deck = createDeck(args);
        Player dealer = new Player("dealer");
        Player sam = new Player("sam");

        Play21 play = new Play21(sam,dealer,deck);
        Player winner = play.play(deck);
        printWinner(winner, winner==sam?dealer:sam);






    }

}
```

Comment: I've downvoted this only because you don't post the specific requirements for your Black Jack implementation - I see a lot of non-standard things here, that don't make sense in a normal Black Jack game. You should post what the requirements for *your* implementation are to help us better understand what's happening, and why.

Comment: Lot spaces.  Why are you afraid type in the exact text?  You assume allCards.size = 52 rather than just use allCards.size. There are more efficient shuffles. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169547/console-single-player-blackjack-versus-a-dealer-again

Comment: @Paparazzi after all the exact interview question is property to the company that is doing the interview. At the same time they don't have property over the Blackjack right :) Maybe I am a bit zealos about it but I feel unconfortable posting it.

Comment: An interview question is the property of company?  That is crazy.

Comment: I've rolled back Rev 7 → 6. On Code Review, we try to keep questions pure, without injecting your own conclusions into the question.

Comment: @200_success OK.

Comment: I find that questions triggering great answers deserve more up-votes

Comment: It is dealer that holds on 17 and that is after playrt has played.  Dealer wins tie.  Missed ace as 1 or 11.  You don't even get to play blackjack.   The program is just two bots of playing each other.  Repeated code.  This is a game where you play blackjack and less code  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169547/console-single-player-blackjack-versus-a-dealer-again

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Avoid repetitive code

> ```
>     public enum CARD {
>
>             S2(2),S3(3),S4(4),S5(5),S6(6),S7(7),S8(8),S9(9),S10(10),SJ(10),SQ(10),SK(10),SA(11),
>             D2(2),D3(3),D4(4),D5(5),D6(6),D7(7),D8(8),D9(9),D10(10),DJ(10),DQ(10),DK(10),DA(11),
>             C2(2),C3(3),C4(4),C5(5),C6(6),C7(7),C8(8),C9(9),C10(10),CJ(10),CQ(10),CK(10),CA(11),
>             H2(2),H3(3),H4(4),H5(5),H6(6),H7(7),H8(8),H9(9),H10(10),HJ(10),HQ(10),HK(10),HA(11);
> ```

Consider breaking this up into two `enum` definitions.

```
public enum Rank {

    TWO(2),
    THREE(3),
    FOUR(4),
    FIVE(5),
    SIX(6),
    SEVEN(7),
    EIGHT(8),
    NINE(9), 
    TEN(10),
    JACK(10),
    QUEEN(10),
    KING(10), 
    ACE(11);
```

and

```
public enum Suit {

    SPADES,
    HEARTS,
    DIAMONDS,
    CLUBS

}
```

Now you don't repeat the points definition four times.

I'm not sure that I'd make these internal to `Deck`.  That makes sense for something like `Map.Entry`, which has no meaning outside `Map`.  But a card matters in multiple situations.  But of course, this something of a judgment call.

I'm more accustomed to putting one `enum` value per line in Java.  This is especially true when passing a value to the constructor.

#### Avoid deprecated types

> ```
>     private Stack<CARD> deck = new Stack<Deck.CARD>();
> ```

`Stack` has been deprecated in favor of `Deque`.

You say `CARD` in one place and `Deck.CARD` in another.

```
    private Deque<Card> deck = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

No deprecated type needed.

Now there is no need for a second type declaration.  The `<>` will do the right thing in newer Java types.

#### No magic numbers

> ```
>         int max = 52;
> ```

Worse, you don't need the magic number.  Consider

```
        int max = CARD.values().length;
```

But I broke `CARD` up into `Rank` and `Suit`.  How about

```
        int max = allCards.size();
```

Now there is an exact match.  But we don't need to do that.

> ```
>             CARD removedCard = allCards.remove(rand.nextInt(max)) ;
> ```

This could be

```
            CARD removedCard = allCards.remove(rand.nextInt(allCards.size()));
```

Now we don't need `max` at all.  We can just reuse the value that already tracks what we want:  the number of cards remaining in the deck.

#### Don't create multiple `Random` objects

What happens if you shuffle two decks within the same seed value?  You'd end up with identical decks.  The fix is to make one `Random` object in `static` context (i.e. at the beginning of the program).

```
    public static final Random random = new Random();
```

Now there is never more than one `Random` object, and it seeds just once.

#### Use the built-in methods

You rolled your own `shuffle` method.  Why?  There's a standard method for that:  `Collections.shuffle`.

#### Choose an access level

> ```
>         Stack<CARD> deck=null;
> ```

This uses the default package private access level.  Why?  Is there something special that causes other classes in the package to need to be able to access it?  If so, I would comment that.

```
        private Deque<CARD> deck;
```

Otherwise, you can make it `private`.

In Java, you don't need to initialize objects to `null`.  It does that for you by default.

#### `try`-with-resources

> ```
>             Scanner scanner=null;
>
>             try {
>                 scanner = new Scanner(file);
> ```

If we write

```
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
```

Then we don't need the `finally` block.  The `Scanner` will be closed automatically, regardless.

#### Redundant logic

You do

> ```
>             if (deck==null) {
>                 return this;
>             }
> ```

Then later, you have

> ```
>             HashSet<CARD> allUniqueCards = new HashSet<>(deck==null?new HashSet<>():deck);
>             // verify uniqueness of cards in case of 52 card condition is met but some are duplicates
>             if (deck==null || allUniqueCards.size()==52) {
> ```

But you know that `deck` could never be `null` here.  Why not just say

```
            Set<CARD> allUniqueCards = new HashSet<>(deck);
            // verify uniqueness of cards in case of 52 card condition is met but some are duplicates
            if (allUniqueCards.size() == VALID_DECK_SIZE) {
```

Now we don't check for things that could never happen.

I also fixed the magic number problem here.

I expect types to be an interface rather than an implementation.  So the original code looks wrong to me.

#### Feedback

> does it really suck so much?

I'm not sure that that's what

> the solution was functionally OK, but was way below their standards of quality code

means.  When I read interview code, I expect it to be exemplary.  It should exhibit good coding standards.  And it should fit my organization's coding standards.  If we're getting a hundred applicants and reviewing code from ten of them, then I expect to be taking the top 30% to the next step.  It's not enough for code to not suck.  It should be good if not great.

I don't mean to be rude in what I say next, but I don't want to soften the harsh edges either.  I want to give the same kind of review that I would give internally in commenting on your code if I was contributing to a hiring decision.

I find things like magic numbers, repetitive code, and multiple calls to `Random` as unacceptable.  I don't want to have to edit this code later.  This is worrisome to me in someone with fifteen years experience, as you are likely somewhat set in your ways.  I would be more willing to overlook these kinds of things in an intern or new developer who might be more malleable.

Some of the decisions you make might make more sense in another language, e.g. C (picking on C because I know it well enough to say; may also fit in other languages that I don't know as well).  But they don't make sense in Java.  In particular, I'm talking about the way that you write your own `shuffle` method, `max`, and explicitly set objects to `null`.  In C, all those would look like reasonable decisions.  In Java, they don't fit.

Some of the decisions fit better in older versions of Java.  The `finally` block with the `Scanner` would have been state of the art in earlier versions of the language.  Now, the `try`-with-resources form is standard.  If this is a Java post, I would expect applicants to know this.

And of course, it is always possible that my judgment is wrong.  Perhaps you would be a better developer than the other person in actuality.  But we'd never know, since I would probably keep looking past this submission.  I'd prefer to hire someone who consistently produces code that I find easy to read and edit later.

Perhaps some of my comments are overly pedantic.  But in my experience, I can hold out for someone who meets my level of pedantry.  So why wouldn't I?

Answer (score 10):

### `main` method

In the `main` method, I don't think you should pass `args` to the `createDeck` function. The `main`'s job is pretty much to check input and be the workflow of your game. After all, if I was to use your `createDeck` function, how would I know what parameters I need to pass to this method to make it work?

In fact, I'm not sure the `createDeck` method itself is useful. If you were to change your `Builder` method to receive a `fileName` instead of a `File`, you could move all that logic at the same place, where it belongs: The `Builder`. Also, `RuntimeException` is pretty vague, I feel you should throw the most specific exception possible, in this case, `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Deck.Builder deckBuilder = Deck.Builder.createNew();

    if(args.length == 0) {
        deckBuilder = deckBuilder.createNew();
    } else if (args.length == 1) {
        deckBuilder = deckBuilder.fromFilePath(args[1]);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected at most one argument");
    }

    Deck deck = deckBuilder.validate().build();
    Player dealer = new Player("dealer");
    Player sam = new Player("sam");

    Play21 play = new Play21(sam,dealer,deck);
    Player winner = play.play(deck);
    printWinner(winner, winner==sam?dealer:sam);
}
```

I don't feel like there's a need to show you the new `fromFilePath` method, it's pretty easy to see what goes in there.

### `Hand` class

The `Hand` doesn't need to know about the specifics of the `BlackJack` game. That means you shouldn't have the 4 methods `hasBlackJack`, `has22`, `lessThan17` and `greaterThan21`. Just expose the `getScore` method and let the game handle the score things. In real life, a hand is just a subset of cards, reflect that in your code. `greaterThan` turned out to be useless, so I removed it.

```
public class Hand {

    private List<CARD> hand = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCard(CARD card) {
        hand.add(card);
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return hand.stream().mapToInt(t->{return t.getPoints();}).sum();
    }

    //Verb-like method, so empty -> isEmpty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return hand.size() == 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        // the sequential stream is not nessesary realy, but it makes it one idea easier to test later.
        String toString = hand.stream().sequential().map(t->{return t.name();}).reduce("", (t,q)->{return t.isEmpty()?q: t+", " + q;});
        return toString;
    }
}
```

Now the `Hand` is pretty lean.

### `Player` class

We'll apply the same pattern for `Player` as we did for `Hand`. All a player is is a `name` and a `hand`.

```
public class Player {

    private String playerName = null;
    private Hand hand = new Hand();

    //Check for null
    public Player(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    //Check for null, change the name to make it a little more explicit
    public void drawACard(Deck deck) {
        hand.addCard(deck.draw());
    }

    public int getHandScore() {
        return hand.getScore();
    }

    public String getPlayerName(){
        return playerName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return playerName + ":" + " " + hand.toString(); 
    }
}
```

### `Play21` class

`Play21` is a weird class name. We're playing BlackJack here right? So why not name it `BlackJackGame`? I think it's much more clear.

In your constructor you don't check for `null` input. You *always* need to check for `null` input in `public` methods/ctor. This'll make debugging much easier. I know it was just an interview question, but I think these little details make the difference between an excellent and an okay answer.

"Printing stuff" should never be in your Domain classes. The `BlackJackGame` has the responsibility to give access to the winning player, but shouldn't have to print it. Imagine you were to change your UI to a web-based game, what purpose would have `printWinner`? That brings another problem up. The `BlackJackGame` shouldn't be the class that has the `main` function. Create a `Program` class, or `Application` or whatever that has the responsibility to be a console app. Now, if you split this you'd have a clear Domain class `BlackJackGame` which handles the game, and a `Program` class that has the responsibility to print/ask input. The `printWinner` method should be in the `Program` class, not the `BlackJameGame` one.

`round1` and `round2` aren't good method names. What do they do and what do they return? A method should pretty much always be verb-like. So `playFirstRound` and `playSecondRound` would be much better. Next, I don't think these methods should return the winner. They're job is to change the scores of the player, that's all.

```
if (dealer.hasBlackJack()&&sam.hasBlackJack()) {
    return sam;
}
else if (sam.hasBlackJack()) {
    return sam;
}
else if(dealer.hasBlackJack()) {
    return dealer;
}
```

Something's off right? You don't need to check if both have blackjack is `sam` is to win. Just check if `sam` has a blackjack, if he does, he wins. Then, check if the dealer has one.

I'll show you how I would have written `BlackJackGame` class and explain the differences afterwards.

```
public class BlackJackGame {

    Player dealer = null;
    Player sam = null;
    Deck deck =  null;
    Player winner = null;
    public static final int BlackJackScore = 21;

    //Check for null
    public BlackJackGame(Player sam,Player dealer,Deck deck) {
        this.sam = sam;
        this.dealer = dealer;
        this.deck = deck;
    }

    private void playFirstRound() {

        sam.drawACard(deck);
        dealer.drawACard(deck);
        sam.drawACard(deck);
        dealer.drawACard(deck);

        int samScore = sam.getHandScore();
        int dealersScore = dealer.getHandScore();

        if(samScore == BlackJackScore) {
            winner = sam;
        } else if (dealersScore == BlackJackScore) {
            winner = dealer;
        }

        //Maybe there's something I don't get in the game
        //what is the difference between 22 and > 21?
        if(samScore > BlackJackScore) {
            winner = dealer;
        } else if (dealerScore > BlackJackScore) {
            winner = sam;
        }
    }

    private void playSecondRound() {
        if (sam.hasEmptyHand() || dealer.hasEmptyHand()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You need to invoke round1 first");
        }

        if(getWinner() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The game is already won");
        }

        //I'm no BlackJack pro, but I think you should have a constant for 17, 
        //explaining what's its significancy
        while(sam.getHandScore() < 17) {
            sam.drawACard(deck);
        }

        int samScore = sam.getHandScore();

        if (samScore > BlackJackScore) {
            winner = dealer;
            return;
        }

        while (samScore > dealer.getHandScore()) {
            dealer.drawACard(deck);
        }

        int dealerScore = dealer.getHandScore();

        if (dealerScore > BlackJackScore) {
            winner = sam;
        } else if (dealerScore > samScore) {
            winner = dealer;
        } else {
            winner = sam;   
        }
    }

    //You had a Deck parameter, but you didn't use it.
    public play(){
        playFirstRound();

        if(getWinner() != null) { return; }

        playSecondRound();
    }

    public Player getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }
}
```

The main difference is that it's now `BlackJackGame`'s responsibility to set a winner, regarding the rules of the game.

To resume, I think the main problem with your code is that it violates the Single Responsibility Principle, your classes do things they shouldn't be doing. Focusing on the Domain will give you leaner classes.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Perhaps you should take a step back and read these answers *objectively*, instead of defending your (bad) programming practices. You came to Code Review wondering why the interviewer thought your code wasn't up-to-snuff, now is not the time to get defensive; use these as learning exercises.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63564/discussion-on-answer-by-topinfrassi-blackjack-game-submitted-as-part-of-intervie).

Answer (score 6):

- The first thing I'd do differently is the representation of a card. Your version contains code duplication, because, while it's true that there are 52 distinct cards, they can be described by two properties that have less than 52 possible values, namely rank and suit. So instead of making one enum for the cards, I would make an enum for the ranks and one enum for the suits, and define a card as a class with these two properties as fields. This would also make it possible to distinguish cards by suit, which can be useful since there are blackjack variants where a suited blackjack pays more than a non-suited blackjack. And if you want to avoid unnecessary object creation, you can make a static factory method to return already existing card objects.
- My next two observations pertain to the following line:

  ```java
  List<CARD> allCards = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(CARD.values()));
  ```

  - First, you are using a raw type constructor. This is not illegal, but by using a raw type constructor instead of a diamond constructor (or an explicit constructor like `new ArrayList<CARD>`), you are denying the type safety at compile-time provided by generics, increasing the potential for bugs. For example, the following code would compile:

    ```java
    List<CARD> allCards = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}));
    ```

    Of course, you wouldn't do something as obviously wrong as this, but if you inadvertently construct a raw `List` with elements of a wrong type, the compiler won't complain when you assign it to a `List<CARD>`.
  - Also, the statement does more than it needs to do because it creates two lists, only one of which is used. It might be convenient to write the code like that, but program-logic-wise, it is more complicated than what you actually want to do, which is simply to add all the enum values to a new `ArrayList`. The most direct way to do that would obviously be creating an empty `ArrayList`, iterating over the array and adding each card to the list. There is a convenience method in `Collections` that does the last two steps:

    ```java
    List<CARD> allCards = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(allCards, CARD.values());
    ```

    Since Java 8, you can also use streams:

    ```java
    List<CARD> allCards = Arrays.stream(CARD.values()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    ```

    Note that, even though the constructor reference `ArrayList::new` doesn't specify a type parameter, the created `ArrayList` will still be generic and not raw (see also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#constructor)).
- The local variable `max` in the method `shuffleDeck()` is redundant and makes the code confusing to read, because it only mirrors the size of `allCards`. It would be less ambiguous if you simply did this:

  ```java
  Random rand = new Random();
  while (allCards.size()>0) {
      CARD removedCard = allCards.remove(rand.nextInt(allCards.size())) ;
      this.deck.add(removedCard);
  }
  ```
- What's the point of the method `createNew()` in `Deck.Builder`? Why not simply declare a `public` no-argument constructor with an empty body? Actually, `fromFile(File)` and `fromStack(Stack)` should be constructors too, because as instance methods, they can only be invoked on an instance of `Builder`, and the only available constructor is the (implicit) no-argument constructor, so the design of declaring instance methods that actually serve the purpose of returning a new `Builder` is really quite convoluted.
- Speaking of `Builder.fromFile(Stack)`, here's a raw type again. What you need is probably `fromFile(Stack<CARD>)`, unless you actually want the method to accept any kind of `Stack` and assign that `Stack` to the field `deck`, which is declared as `Stack<CARD>` (the assignment itself would succeed), so that a `ClassCastException` is thrown at runtime when accessing the elements of `deck`, because someone passed a `Stack<BigInteger>` as a joke and a `BigInteger` cannot be cast to `CARD`.
- About `Builder.validate()`: You already check `deck` for being `null` in the beginning, so you don't need to consider this case later on in the method. Also, in the second step, you might as well check if `deck.size() != 52` instead of `deck.size() > 52`, because if `deck.Size() < 52`, the same exception will be thrown later anyway, the only difference being that you create a new `HashSet` in between.
- What is actually the purpose of the `Deck.Builder` class? It has three methods that are really constructors in disguise, one `validate()` method that is never called anywhere in the quasi-constructors, its only state is a `Stack<CARD>`, just like that of a `Deck`, and the only remaining method, `build()`, does nothing but invoke one of the two dubious `private` constructors of `Deck`, optionally passing its own `Stack<Card>` to it. It doesn't even call `validate()`, either. So what is the point of this class?
- There is a shortcut for what you do in `Deck.toString()`:

  ```java
  return deck.stream().map(CARD::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
  ```
- I have not much to say about the hand class, because I agree with everything TopinFrassi said about it. Just one more heads-up: A hand having a score of 21 is not equivalent to a hand being a blackjack. Explaining why this is the case is outside the scope of this question, because it pertains to the rules of blackjack and not to programming.

Answer (score 5):

The player class doesn't need to exist. All it does hold a name and forward operations to its hand.

Your shuffle assumes the deck starts out empty. It is a proper shuffle so you did that right. However there exists a `Collections.shuffle(List)` for your shuffling needs.

The ace card can have 2 possible values 1 and 11, you didn't account for that at all.

Your builder doesn't do any defensive copies which would let using code modify the internals of Deck.

Answer (score 5):

I usually don't do Java code, and TopinFrassi covered most of what I wanted to write, but

- `CARD` does not follow the [Java enum naming convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).
- This

  ```
  public String toString() {
    // the sequential stream is not nessesary realy, but it makes it one idea easier to test later.
    String toString = hand.stream().sequential().map(t->{return t.name();}).reduce("", (t,q)->{return t.isEmpty()?q: t+", " + q;});
    return toString;
  }
  ```

  should be

  ```
  public String toString() {
    // the sequential stream is not nessesary realy, but it makes it one idea easier to test later.
    return hand.stream().sequential().map(t->{return t.name();}).reduce("", (t,q)->{return t.isEmpty()?q: t+", " + q;});
  }
  ```

  or possibly you could have used `String.join` to make this more readable (there is too much on that one line)
- I would have preferred to see `int cardsLeft = allCards.size();` instead of `int max = 52;`
- You use `52` in a few places, this should be a well named constant on top
- This part

  ```
     if (deck.size()>52) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Critical error, deck is not initialized correctly.You need 52 unique cards.");

      }
  ```

  is odd, why not `deck.size()!=52` since 51 or fewer cards are bad as well? Not to mention that you check the count of unique cards later on. So you can throw away this whole `if` statement, and the user will not see a difference.
- `if (deck==null || allUniqueCards.size()==52) {` <- seems you checked for `null` earlier on, why check again?
- If I read your code correctly, then shuffling a deck twice will give you a deck with 104 cards, that just seems wrong. Perhaps call it `fillDeck`?

Comment: It appears that we nearly had a race-condition here ;) (with regard to our answers)

Comment: Your answer is way better than mine, but we definitely saw the same things

Answer (score -2):

If I would have to judge this I would would ask: *Where are the **UnitTests**?*

Most software projects rapidly grow beyond the point where each and very developer knows every line of code well enough to predict side effects of a change. UnitTests give *immediate feedback* if a change accidentally broke some intended behavior. They also *document* what behavior you really implemented (intentionally).

So I would consider missing UnitTest being "way below *my* coding standards.

---

BTW: UnitTest can only protect code (and requirements) they cover. The only way to reliably create a sufficient coverage is doing [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).